# Are there any other (meta)stable oxygen molecules beyond O3?

Tags: bond, molecules, molecular-structure

Apart from Ozone, are there any longer oxygen molecules that are at least stable for short amounts of time? What configurations would that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my German version of *Holleman-Wiberg: Inorganic Chemistry* there is one additional, very short lived species, the so called tetraoxygen. A short article is also available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraoxygen).

Wiberg describes it's synthesis from dioxygen in a mass-spectrometer employing the "neutralisation-reionisation-technique" (I am translating and paraphrasing at the same time, there might be something lost in translation.) It's stable time frame is in the micro second area. The decomposition barrier of $\ce{O4}$ is about 25 kJ/mol. The structure is not known, but most likely an aggregate of two oxygen molecules, i.e. $\ce{(O2)2}$. In lower concentrations $\ce{O4}$ might be found in liquid oxygen and they may be a template for the  ε-high pressure modification of solid oxygen forming at 0.6 Mbar.

1. [Holleman, A., Wiberg, N., Wiberg, E., *et al.* (2008). *Lehrbuch der Anorganischen Chemie*. Berlin, Boston: De Gruyter.](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/19732) Kapitel XIII 1.1.4 *Kurzlebige Sauerstoffspezies*. S. 513f.  (in german)
2. Translation of the 101st edition available as [Egon Wiberg and Nils Wiberg (2001) Holleman, Wiberg. Inorganic Chemistry. Academic Press.](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Mtth5g59dEIC)

Comment: According to wikipedia the epsilon phase of solid oxygen referred to in the answer has been shown by X-ray crystallography to contain O8 molecules. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen